# I am getting redirected to wamp home page when typing anything in the drupal site's path

Tags: apache, drupal-7, wamp

The problem i am facing is that whenenver I am typing the path of any sub directory n my website like **localhost/MySiteName/register** I am getting redirected towards the wamphome page . Any clicks after that on the wamphome page is giving path like (if i click on phpmyadmin) **localhost/MySiteName/register/phpmyadmin** . I have looked extensively through the code and the net but could not make out why such thing is happening ?

Comment: check your `.htaccess` file, could be some problem with url rewrite.

Comment: @lihsus there is no problem with the .htaccess file i checked

Comment: If you want to use complex sites like drupal you woudl be well advised to create a Virtual Host within Apache for it to run in. Running in a subfolder of the DocumentRoot will probably always cause you problems, especially when you come to move the site to a live server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First check your .htaccess file , is it present or not. If it is present then follow the below mention steps.

1. Open your wamp and click on it.
2. Now go to Apache>>Apache Modules
3. And check rewrite_module and then restart you WAMP. Please refer attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I did this, and once I did it, I got an internal server error

Comment: I have the rewrite_module enabled but it's still not working. It works for a new drupal install, but not for my site, which i'm importing from a live server.